# Neighbor's AC Unit Causing Ceiling Fan Hum?

Tags: electrical, air-conditioning, ceiling-fan

One day last month my downstairs neighbor's bedroom ceiling fan started to become very noticeable. It's not loud, but it keeps me up at night. I can tell when it's on just by walking past my bedroom even when the door is closed. I assumed there was something wrong with the fan, but after speaking with her, the timing seems to have coincided with her installing a window AC unit.

So my question is, can running the AC unit and fan at the same time cause a hum in the fan? If so, is there anything that can be done to fix it? Could connecting the AC unit to a different outlet in the bedroom spread out the power more evenly? Thanks.

Comment: I would think that all the outlets in a bedroom are on the same circuit, about a 70 to 80% chance.  Is it an electrical hum(not good), or more like a vibration type hum?

Comment: It's not a constant hum. It's more like a vibration that's in time with the rotation of the blades.

Comment: If it only happens when the fan and AC is on together, I would suggest your neighbour turn off the fan.  The AC should move the air when it is on without the fan being on together.  I think the AC and the fan on together sets up a type of vibration that adds together.  Might be the way the room is built, one or both are mounted too loose or too tight, or something else.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll follow up with her.